# How to get the volume of elements with certain type of material in Abaqus ODB by means of Python

Tags: python, abaqus

I need to calculate the total volume of elements with a certain type of material, then calculate that part of them in which some **UVARM** variable is greater than 1, and then define the ratio between these volumes.

The problem is that I cannot find how to filter out the elements exactly by name of material, not by section, part instance or element set, since the elements of interest are evenly distributed among these sections, sets etc.

Thank you

Comment: how have you assigned different materials within a section?

Comment: sorry, probably my description was unclear. Each element corresponds to a single element set, and each element set corresponds to a single section. There are thousands of elements in the part, and 7 types of material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to loop over every element and look at the sectionCategory for each:

```
element.sectionCategory.name
```

> 'solid < materialname >'

so you build a full list something like:

```
steelels = [ el.label for el in instance.elements if el.sectionCategory.name == 'solid < steel >']
```

Really the preferred approach here is to create the appropriate element sets as you build the model.

Comment: thank you, in general this works, but due to some reason, in my case some of the materials get combined in the same sectionCategory. In other words, the number of sectionCategories is less than the number of materials. Unfortunatelly, I cannot change the approach to the sections/sets assignment, because I get the .inp-files from outside and they contain too complicated geometry to change it manually.

Comment: if all else fails it wouldn't be that difficult to write a script to scan the inp file for all the section specifications..

Comment: definitely something strange. See edit, I've confirmed I can correctly extract element labels, but something goes wrong extracting actual element objects ( even `getElementFromLabel` doesnt work right for an instance with multiple sections) . Someone with time to deal with simula support should report as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the model attributes before writing the .inp file to 'do not use parts and assemblies in input files' and run the simulation with this input you probably won't get any issues when accessing the odb.

```
part_instance = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PART-1-1']
elLabels = [ v.label for v in part_instance.elements if v.sectionCategory.name == 'solid < DUMMY_MATERIAL >']
```